# Wifi Channel vs a Sub 1 GHz channel of same width

Tags: rf, wifi, 433mhz

If the same channel-width is allocated for a WiFi channel and also for a Sub-1 GHz channel, would the maximum allowable speed be the same for both channels theoretically?

If they differ, what is the theory behind the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the channel width and SNR are the same, then the channel capacity in bits per second is the same.

Comment: @alex.forenrich So does WiFi offer faster speeds because channel bandwidth of Wifi is usually higher than a Sub-1 channel? Thank You for your time

Comment: Pretty much. Generally, the higher the center frequency, the more bandwidth can be allocated.